# Data required for the raster array is less than the data provided by BMP file Array

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I declared my buffered image like this:

```
BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int pixel[] = ((DataBufferInt) buff.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                    .getData();
            System.out.println(pixel.length);
```

It gives me raster data required into the `pixel[]`

I have the image pixel data from random access file. But the image data required for this height and width is greater than what is given by the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it to be a BMP image.... Please handle the padding required by the BMP image....

Use this code....

```
        int padding = 0;
        int extra = 0;
        extra = (width * 3) % 4;
        if (extra != 0)
            padding = (4 - extra);
```

Now skip the padding bytes like this while filling the pixel array...

```
random-access-file-object-name.skipBytes(padding);
```